# DAG "DAG_NAME" seems to be missing from DagBag for Dynamic Dag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to create dynamic DAG in GCP, we already have some dynamic dag created for different purpose which are working perfectly fine.

But Now,I am following the sma eapproach for creating dynamic dag as follows,

1. read config table(BigQuery)
2. based on configuration inserted in the config tables it'll create dynamic dag
3. Dag getting creating and showing in the Dag list.
4. White trying to view it , i am clicking on it then it's showing the error DAG `"DAG_NAME" seems to be missing from DagBag`

I have not found anything in logs.

[image: Dag Created]

[image: Dag Error]

Comment: Could to try Restarting the Airflow web server? Also, can you check whether your dag code is having any errors?